# what is notification channel id?notifications not work in api 27

Tags: android, api, notifications

I updated my project api target to 27 and all notifications were disabled.
What's the difference between notification in api 26 and 27?

```
        Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true).build();
        notif.ledARGB = 0xFFff0000;
        notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notif.ledOnMS = 100;
        notif.ledOffMS = 100;

        NotificationManager notificationCompatManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationCompatManager.notify(0, notif);
```

Comment: Everybody who viewed this question in the first minute has upvoted it, eh? How nice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990995/on-android-8-oreo-api-26-and-later-notification-does-not-display

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As stated in the [Android developers website](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels):

> Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be
> assigned to a channel. For each channel, you can set the visual and
> auditory behavior that is applied to all notifications in that
> channel. Then, users can change these settings and decide which
> notification channels from your app should be intrusive or visible at
> all.

So You can use this method to show notification in both -27 and +27 apis :

Java :

```
    void showNotification(String title, String message) {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("YOUR_CHANNEL_ID",
                "YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("YOUR_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION");
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR_CHANNEL_ID")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // notification icon
            .setContentTitle(title) // title for notification
            .setContentText(message)// message for notification
            .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ACTIVITY_NAME.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Kotlin :

```
fun showNotification(title: String, message: String) {
    val mNotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel("YOUR_CHANNEL_ID",
                "YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        channel.description = "YOUR_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION"
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, "YOUR_CHANNEL_ID")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // notification icon
            .setContentTitle(title) // title for notification
            .setContentText(message)// message for notification
            .setAutoCancel(true) // clear notification after click
    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, ACTIVITY_NAME::class.java)
    val pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi)
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build())
}
```

**Note**: If you want to show heads-up notification, you can set the importance of your channel and your notification as HIGH, **AND** remove your app and install it again.

**UPDATE ON ANDROID 13+:**

If you want to post show notifications on Android 13+, you need to get a runtime permission from the user. To get the permission add this line to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

And in your app, you can get the permission like this:

```
private fun getNotificationPermission() {
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU &&
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS), 100)
    }
}
```

Comment: what is channel id? Please send more details

Comment: please see this article https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-android-o-notification-channels-94cd274f604c

Comment: thanks. is there any good library to manage notifications? (check integration)

Comment: what do u mean by check integration?

Comment: I am looking for a good solution for show notification in android and manage different api versions of android .

Comment: i haven't seen any library for that. i think you can use this handy method to create your notifications.