# NotificationService: No Channel found on Android 8.0 with Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-support-library

I saw threads like this: [NotificationChannel issue in Android O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668079/notificationchannel-issue-in-android-o)

But the problem here is that we are using Unity3d with support-v4-24.0.0. It's not possible to update it. For example, [Facebook plugin doesn't work with new support library](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/issues/125).

Is it possible to make working notifications on 8.0 devices with old support library?

Comment: Try to set targetSdk of your project to 25

Comment: They recommend to use "Automatic (highest installed)" option https://forum.unity.com/threads/anyone-know-if-unity-supports-android-8-android-o-api-26-in-5-6-2.479756/#post-3229557