# Android : Firebase remote config failed to fetch parameters

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, firebase-remote-config

I am trying to run Remote config in my app but everytime I got the same error and I don't know how to solve it...

I followed this tutorial : [Use Firebase Remote Config on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android)

So I first, I added the dependency :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.4.2'
```

In the activity's class, I added these lines :

```
private FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
....
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    Task<Void> fetch = remoteConfig.fetch(0);
    fetch.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            remoteConfig.activateFetched();

            remoteConfig.getLong("version_code");
        }
    });
    ....
}
```

(I added "version_code" parameter to Firebase console / Remote config and I published modifications)

When I run the app, I get always this error :

[image]

Any idea please ? 
Thanks

Comment: The error is not caused by Firebase Remote Config.  It is the result of some problem with your setup for Notifications.  See this related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44489657/4815718.  As the warning message indicates, you should look in your logcat out for more details.  When you find them, add them to your post.

Comment: There is no notification in this activity, and I get the message only when I add the code lines...

Comment: Did you look in logcat output for "more details"?

Comment: 10-30 22:52:52.696 1525-2393/system_process E/NotificationService: No Channel found for pkg=com.utils, channelId=null, id=10436, tag=null, opPkg=com.dekr, callingUid=10084, userId=0, incomingUserId=0, notificationUid=10084, notification=Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x110 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)

Comment: Do you recognize the package name "com.dekr"? Maybe related to [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dekr&hl=en)?

Comment: Yes I recognize this package name