# Why are my Toast messages overlapping?

Tags: android, android-toast

Concurrent `Toast`s have always appeared consecutively, but on my new device running SDK 27 (8.1.1) they appear concurrently, overlapping.

I believe it changed in Android SDK 27 but I can't find any documentation to support it. Can anyone confirm or deny this? I need to know if should implement a version-specific workaround.

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm, but I never bothered to really look into it. Someone has created a bug report for it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50062913.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21268886/5885018