# Notification is not displaying

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I created a notification option for my project. It consists of two classes: `alarmreceiver` (called by `AlarmManager`) and a `Notificationhelper` class which creates the notification.

When I run my program, instead of displaying a notification it crashes. Someone please help me to resolve this. I attached my code here

Mainactivity

```
    private void notification(String botime, String bodate){
                      Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
                      cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,21);
                      cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,5);
                      cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),alarmreceiver.class);
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(booking.this,1,intent,0);
                        //if(cal.before(Calendar.getInstance()))
                        //{
                            //cal.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
                        //}
                        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);  
}
```

AlarmReceiver

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class alarmreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Notificationhelper notificationhelper=new Notificationhelper(context);
        NotificationCompat.Builder nb=notificationhelper.getchannelNotification("Remainder",
                "Remainder for your room booking");
        notificationhelper.getManager().notify(1,nb.build());
    }
}
```

Notificationhelper

```
package com.example.sarukesi.seminarbook;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;

public class Notificationhelper extends ContextWrapper {
    public static final String channelid="channelid";
    public static final String channelname = "channel";
    private NotificationManager mmanager;
    public Notificationhelper(Context base) {
        super(base);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createchannels();
        }
    }

    private void createchannels() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel=new NotificationChannel(channelid,channelname, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
            notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        }
    }
    public NotificationManager getManager(){
        if(mmanager==null){
            mmanager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
        return mmanager;
    }
    public android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder getchannelNotification(String title,String message){
        return new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),channelid)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does logcat say when the app crashes?

Comment: Post your crash logs

Comment: 07-19 20:05:00.696 496-3098/system_process E/EGL_emulation: tid 3098: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
07-19 20:05:00.696 496-3098/system_process W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xd2d189a0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
07-19 20:05:02.193 1182-1232/com.genymotion.genyd W/GenydService: unknown message set_device_clipboard 
07-19 20:05:02.396 496-496/system_process W/WindowManager: removeWindowToken: Attempted to remove non-existing token: android.os.Binder@6a20f7c
07-19 20:05:02.445 496-3895/system_process V/rsC++: RS Message thread e

Comment: @prashant17  i posted the log info but i dont know how to resolve it

Comment: @spartygw i now posted it

Comment: The logcat output you added in a comment is not related to your app. You need to capture logcat during the error and it will likely be obvious how to solve once you see the log. Also don't put logcat ouptut in a comment, the formatting is awful. Amend the original question with logcat output.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489657/android-o-reporting-notification-not-posted-to-channel-but-it-is